# Detecting if a linkedlist has loop in JS

Tags: javascript, linked-list

How can i see if a linkedlist has a loop in js when i cant equate two nodes? I have seen this approach online using a fast pointer and slow pointer but that requires us to equate the fast and slow pointer nodes:

```
class SLLNode{
    constructor(data)
  {
    this.data = data
    this.next = null
  }
}

class ll {
    constructor(data){
        this.head = new SLLNode(data)
    }
}

function hasCycle(l) {
  var head = l.head
  var slow, fast;

  if(!head || !head.next) return false;

    slow = head;
    fast = head;

    if(head.next === head) return true;

    while(fast.next.next) {

      slow = slow.next;
      fast = fast.next.next;

      if(slow ===fast){ return true;}
    }

  return false;
}
var l = new ll(2)

var m = new ll(2)
var my_node1 = new SLLNode(1)

var my_node2 = new SLLNode(2)

var my_node3 = new SLLNode(3)
//assigning head
l.head = my_node1
//connecting linked list
l.head.next=my_node2;
l.head.next.next=my_node3;
l.head.next.next.next=my_node1; //cycle

console.log(hasCycle(l))
```

I keep getting false on this when it should be true. How can we compare two nodes in js

Comment: checking two objects via `===` would return true if they are literally the same object, e.g., `a = new Number(42); b = a` but not if the two objects with similar data contained `a = new Number(42); b = new Number(42)`. So do you expect the list to link literally to the same node or to a node that has the same data as the one before?

Comment: So i am expecting that the linkedlist links to the same node as before.

Comment: Your code works for me, it returns `true`. You can use `===` operator to compare nodes in JS.